# GStreamer 1.14.4 building error with Buildroot

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I ran into the following error when building [GStreamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) 1.14.4:

```
/build/gstreamer1-1.14.4/libs/gst/controller »
  CC       libgstcontroller_1.0_la-controller-enumtypes.lo
controller-enumtypes.c:6:1: error: « \ » stray in program
 \#include "gstinterpolationcontrolsource.h"
 ^
controller-enumtypes.c:6:2: error: « # » stray in program
 \#include "gstinterpolationcontrolsource.h"
  ^
controller-enumtypes.c:6:11: error: expected « = », « , », « ; », « asm » or « __attribute__ » before string constant
 \#include "gstinterpolationcontrolsource.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
controller-enumtypes.c:7:1: error: « \ » stray in program
 \#include "gstlfocontrolsource.h"
 ^
controller-enumtypes.c:7:2: error: « # » stray in program
 \#include "gstlfocontrolsource.h"

...
```

I am compiling for Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ on [Debian 11 (Bullseye)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_11_(Bullseye)) (Bullseye) (GNU Make 4.3, GCC (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110) and the cross compiler is arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-7.4.0. Before that the compilation was OK on [Linux Mint 18.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Releases) (Sonya).

It seems to be related to generated code:

```
/* controller-enumtypes.c */
/* This file is generated by glib-mkenums, do not modify it. This code is licensed under the same license as the containing project. Note that it links to GLib, so must comply with the LGPL linking clauses. */

#include "controller-enumtypes.h"

\#include "gstinterpolationcontrolsource.h"
\#include "gstlfocontrolsource.h"

...
```

In the line `\#include "gstinterpolationcontrolsource.h"`, there is an extra `"\"` which is invalid syntax.

How can I properly fix this package with Buildroot 2019.02.9?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://bugs.gentoo.org/705974, this happens due to the use of make 4.3 on your new machine. make 4.3 was released in January 2020, so it wasn't a version of make that we could have tested back when Buildroot 2019.02 was released.

In the Gentoo bug report above, you can find a patch that solves the issue. However, keep in mind that Buildroot 2019.02.x is no longer maintained: we maintain the long-term support releases during one year.

Comment: Unfortunately the gstreamer package is not the only issue so i had to fall back to Debian Buster and it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I am having this problem with a Gstreamer 1.14.4 distribution inside Buildroot (for cross-compilation to an ARM 32-bit embedded device) and the problem happens not only inside controller package but also at least for gst1-plugins-base (it will probably happen to -good, -bad and -ugly and who knows which else - I will know as soon as I manage to adapt the patch in the link sent above forgst1-plugins-base and make it work). Will share the patches here if I manage to make it fix the compilation process. BTW, the provided patch works like a charm inside Buildroot, just renumber the filename accordingly, put it inside package/gstreamer1/gstreamer1 and run make... the controller module compiles perfectly now... Just need now to adapt for the other modules where the very same kind of problem (\#include) happens...

Comment: Please format your answer according to .md rules